# Is it possible to constraint a customization point object?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to constraint a customization point object (here, `serialize`) with a concept (`serializable`):

```
    #include <vector>
    
    // The concept
    template <class T>
    concept serializable = requires (T const& t) 
    { 
        serialize (t); 
    };
    
    namespace detail
    {
        // For ints
        auto serialize (int) { return 1; }
    
        // For std::vector of serializable type
        template <class T>
        requires serializable <T>
        auto serialize (std::vector <T> const&)
        {
            return 2;
        }
    
        struct serialize_fn
        {
            template <class T> 
            constexpr auto operator() (T&& t) const
            {
                return serialize (std::forward <T> (t));
            }
        };
    }
    // The CPO
    constexpr inline auto serialize = detail::serialize_fn {};
    
    int main ()
    {
        serialize (2);
        serialize (std::vector { 1, 2, 3 });
    }
```

The call with the vector as argument fails, the compiler (GCC 12, clang 13) complains that the require expression `serialize(int)` is invalid. I don't understand why.

Edit: error message (gcc):

```
q.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr auto detail::serialize_fn::operator()(T&&) const [with T = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]’:
q.cpp:43:19:   required from here
q.cpp:33:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘serialize(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’
   33 |                 return serialize (std::forward <T> (t));
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
q.cpp:22:14: note: candidate: ‘template<class T>  requires  serializable<T> auto detail::serialize(const std::vector<T>&)’
   22 |         auto serialize (std::vector <T> const&)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
q.cpp:22:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
q.cpp:22:14: note: constraints not satisfied
q.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T>  requires  serializable<T> auto detail::serialize(const std::vector<T>&) [with T = int]’:
q.cpp:33:34:   required from ‘constexpr auto detail::serialize_fn::operator()(T&&) const [with T = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]’
q.cpp:43:19:   required from here
q.cpp:9:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘serializable<T>’ [with T = int]
q.cpp:9:28:   in requirements with ‘const T& t’ [with T = int]
q.cpp:11:19: note: the required expression ‘serialize(t)’ is invalid
   11 |         serialize (t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
q.cpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr auto detail::serialize_fn::operator()(T&&) const [with T = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]’:
q.cpp:43:19:   required from here
cc1plus: note: set ‘-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=’ to at least 2 for more detail
q.cpp:17:14: note: candidate: ‘auto detail::serialize(int)’
   17 |         auto serialize (int) { return 1; }
      |              ^~~~~~~~~
q.cpp:17:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >’ to ‘int’
   17 |         auto serialize (int) { return 1; }
      |                         ^~~
make: *** [<builtin>: q] Error 1
```

Comment: what is the complaint? Please include the complete error message in the question

Comment: This code seems to be kinda illogical to me. You're putting constraint on serialize function, and the constraint is checked by a concept that checks whether the "serialize" function can be invoked on the object that you passed.

Comment: How can you put constraint to a function which is being used within the constraint?

Comment: The concept still has to obey regular C++ name lookup rules. The integer (and all non-adl) version(s) **must be** visible for name lookup at the point the concept is defined.

Comment: Focus on what `serialize` *does* to *whom* and write constraints about that.

Comment: [Fix, sort of](https://godbolt.org/z/vY6Ws19vo) (not the best one).

Comment: `serialize_fn` can be called with anything, so `serializable` would allow all types...